# Overriding inherited prototype method and calling the original one inside the new one

Tags: javascript, inheritance, overriding, prototype

In the following piece of code, how can I access the `A.prototype.log` inside of `B.prototype.log`?

```
function A() {}

A.prototype.log = function () {
    console.log("A");
};

function B() {}

B.prototype = Object.create(A.prototype);
B.prototype.constructor = B;

B.prototype.log = function () {
    //call A.prototype.log here
    console.log("B");
};

var b = new B();
b.log();
```

I know I could just write `A.prototype.log.call(this)` but I thought maybe there is a more elegant way, that lets me call it in a relative way, like "call the method 'log' of the next higher instance in the prototype chain". Is something like this possible?

Comment: actually, `A.prototype.log.call(this)` was exactly what I searched for. Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use [`Object.getPrototypeOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/getPrototypeOf)

```
...
B.prototype.log = function () {
    Object.getPrototypeOf (B.prototype).log.call(this)
    console.log("B");
};
...
b.log(); //A B
```

*Note: Object.getPrototypeOf is ECMASript 5, see the [compatibility](http://kangax.github.io/es5-compat-table/)*

---

There is also the **non standard** and deprecated [`__proto__`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/proto) property *([compatibility](http://kangax.github.io/es5-compat-table/non-standard/))* which

> references the same object as its internal [[Prototype]]

and would allow you to call your `A`s' log method like this

`B.prototype.__proto__.log.call(this)`

But

> the preferred method is to use Object.getPrototypeOf.

Comment: @C5H8NNaO4 there is a type in the code, the correct one is `Object.getPrototypeOf ( B.prototype.log) .call(this)`